# Parsing CSV file with Pandas in Python 3

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am trying to parse a movie database with Python 3.
How can I parse genres of a movie with different variables?
For example:

```
1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy
2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children|Fantasy
```

First value is movie_id, second is movie_name, and the third values are genres but I want to parse them as separate variables that belong to corresponding movie. In other words, I want second separator to my database as "|". How can I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
header = ["movie_id", "title", "genres"]
movie_db = pd.read_csv("movielens/movies.csv", sep=",", names=header)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use separator `,|` but is necessary first row have to contains all possible genres:

```
df = pd.read_csv("movielens/movies.csv", sep="[,|]", header=None, engine='python')
print (df)
   0                 1          2          3         4       5        6
0  1  Toy Story (1995)  Adventure  Animation  Children  Comedy  Fantasy
1  2    Jumanji (1995)  Adventure   Children   Fantasy    None     None
```

But here is better create new columns by categories and set to `1` if category exist in row by [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and add to original columns by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
movie_db = pd.read_csv("movielens/movies.csv", sep=",", names=header)
```

```
df =  movie_db.join(movie_db.pop('genres').str.get_dummies())
print (df)
   movie_id             title  Adventure  Animation  Children  Comedy  Fantasy
0         1  Toy Story (1995)          1          1         1       1        1
1         2    Jumanji (1995)          1          0         1       0        1
```

But if need columns is possible use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `|`:

```
df = movie_db.join(movie_db.pop('genres').str.split('|', expand=True))
print (df)
   movie_id             title          0          1         2       3        4
0         1  Toy Story (1995)  Adventure  Animation  Children  Comedy  Fantasy
1         2    Jumanji (1995)  Adventure   Children   Fantasy    None     None
```